# Joining of two tables

Tags: sql, join

I am a new and am having some trouble with joining two tables. 
table1: (topicID, questionID) where topicID is the primary key. For each topicID, there are many questionID's.

Now, I have a table2 with questioIDs and I want to get all those topicID's from table1 which have atleast one entry for each questionID in table2.

I would appreciate any help.

```
create table table1(
    topicID int,
    questionid int)
create table table2
(
    questionid int
)
insert into table1
select 1,1
union all
select 2,1
union all
select 2,2
union all
select 2,4
union all
select 1,2
union all
select 1,6

insert into table2 
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 6
```

Using table1 and table2 above, the query should return topicID as 2 as only this has atleast one entry for each questionID's in table2.

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask something that is on Page 1 of almost any SQL reference.

Comment: Next time I will make sure that I ask only those questions which "others" think is a question.

Comment: Just do some due diligence first.  Very very basic functions in SQL are super common to ask about, and pretty much useless to anyone else who ever sees them.  The point of SO is to make an archival resource of how to solve issues.  This adds no value.

Comment: Also, @Ratan how long will you say you are "New to SQL"?  You used the same argument for a basic `LEFT JOIN` question 11 months ago.

Comment: I get your point above and about "being new", I will call myself new till I think I know enough to call my self an expert.

Comment: @JNK: seriously, show me a book on SQL where relational division is discussed anywhere near page one. BTW `JOIN` and `DIVIDE` are operators, not functions.

Comment: @JNK ... the problem is that, unless the OP is already familiar with relational division, they don't know what to call it, hence why they used the term join, I guess. Giving an example was fair enough (see [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) for a similar take: "This is easier to explain with an example"), shame on you for not reading past the question title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Because your spec states "has at least one entry for each questionID", I think you should be looking at [division with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

p.s. this is not a topic you'll find "on Page 1 of almost any SQL reference", rather it is one of the more obscure relational operators!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT topicID
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY topicID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT questionid) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
```

Comment: The only correct query. Rest all just try to answer a question without reading it properly.

Comment: Though the query gives the correct result, but what if the count was same but they were different questionID's. Then the result will not be correct?

Comment: @Ratan: That's why I'm counting *DISTINCT* questionid values.

Comment: I guess my example was not clear, so I have edited the table values above. If you would run your query, you will get both topicID 1 and 2 as your result, which will not be correct.

Comment: @Ratan: I would argue that your example is flawed. You have a `questionid` of 4 in `table1` that does not exist in `table2`. That violates the (implied) relationship between the two tables.

Comment: I would +2 if I could, @JoeStefanelli.  He is changing the question now and suddenly the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: Sorry about that, the table1 has more columns than just topicID and questionID and so the combination of topicID and questionID works as the primary key here. I have been trying to resolve this for past 2 days and cannot. I will try to explain my question more here: There is a table 1 which has some topicID's. For each topicID there are some x number of questionID's along with their dateAnswered and answerKey and other stuff. I need to find  how many of these topicID's in this table are complete and they called complete only if they have an entry for each questionID in table2.

Comment: So, I just added one more line to your code before grouping and it seems to work fine: join table1.questionid = table2.questionid. And change having count(distinct questionid) to having count(*). (Help from another forum)